# Weight attribute accidentally deleted

Tags: attributes

During the creation and deletion of some of the attributes in the past, I accidentally deleted the attribute weight. Now I want to fix this by creating the attribute again but I get the error The attribute code 'weight' is reserved by the system. Try another attribute code.

A backup restore is not an option because it's been some time since I've removed it. But now i want to use weight for shipping again so I need this.

How can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create an separate attribute and then edit it in the database, table: eav_attribute with these values,

attribute_id: 80

attribute_code: weight

I'm not sure if this is the correct way but it would be the first thing I would try.